# Calling an in memory file by string as parameter in method (Java)

Tags: java, in-memory

I am working on calling a main(String[] args) method on quite large datasets and files. The method uses a number parameter files, which it calls using their filenames. However, because of the file size, it takes too long and is not really realistic. Therefore, I have decided to break down the files into small chunks. The simplest idea was to read the main file and write each chunk to  a smaller file and call the method a certain number of times. This takes still some time and is not optimal. Therefore, I am curious whether I can simply create an in memory file and call it as a parameter of my method. Is this possible?

Below is a copy of my code. I can create the reference files in preprocessing, but I would specifically like to generate the target file in memory and call it in.

Thanks!

```
String target = "targetFile.txt";
String ref = "referenceFile.txt";
String output = "outputFile.txt";

String[] imputationArgs = new String[]{ref, target, output};
Main.main(imputationArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your java process should be able to hold your file/s in-memory no matter how much parts you've split your input. you can control the memory allocation of your process by passing JVM parameters like `java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m`

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) post for more information.